# react-router-dom - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, antd

While using react-router-dom 5.3.0, I am opening a modal but am not changing route, and this error appears.

I have since downgraded react-router-dom to 5.2.0 and this error does not appear.

Any help is much appreciated :-)

[image: Error Message]

Comment: `context.location` is not defined

Comment: Hi @BENARDPatrick, could you expand a bit more, I'm not sure what to do with this in terms of my code.

Comment: You see the second stack trace error ? line 104 `createPath(context.location)` ? It calls the function `createPath` and inside it, the line 47 location is undefined. So `context.location` is undefined.... In your code, you can wait that `context.location` has a wanted value...

Comment: Thanks @BENARDPatrick.  All of these errors take place within a package (which I believe is react-router-dom) in my node_modules.  So I was thinking that the problem lies in the package?

Comment: Anyway, I just upgraded react-router-dom again to the latest version and I can't actually replicate the problem, lets see if the problem has now gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error after upgrading the react-router-dom version when I tried accessing the current URL with `location.pathname` .

Using the `useLocation()` hook solved my problem:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

// getting current pathname with custom hook

const useName = () => {
const location = useLocation();
return location.pathname;
}
```